# Is there a way to get a username from a user_id from stored user_id's even if they aren't on the same server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if it's possible to get a username from a user id globally on discord.

within a Cog, I am currently using the line below to retrieve information if the search is local.
`self.ctx.guild.get_member`

But I'm hoping to expand into a global search, but I'm not even sure if it's possible
I was also thinking if I can't get the username, I'd want to change the NULL return I get into something like "External User"

I'm using this line to make the search and iterate through a list (Local version)

```py
table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.guild.get_member(entry[0])} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n' for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))
```

Comment: `get_member` returns from cache. `fetch_user` will return a _user_ from the API. (But it will not be related to a guild, but rather the user itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `user = self.get_user(USERID)` to get any user on discord, and `user.name` to get their username. Look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user to find more about `get_user`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer only works if you have the user cached. This is not guaranteed, and in larger bots is almost guaranteed to not be unless you have the members intent enabled.

You can use [bot.fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#discord.Client.fetch_user), which will give you the user object regardless of your cache. It's still a good idea to check .get_user first.

I often have a function like this in my code:

```py
def get_or_fetch_user(bot, user_id):
    user = bot.get_user(user_id)
    if not user:  # the user isn't in the cache, or it doesn't exist
        try:
            user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
        except discord.NotFound:  # fetch_user raises an error if the user doesn't exist
            user = None
    return user
```

Comment: the one thing is i don't know how to implement it into the line that writes the embded content 
`table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.guild.get_member(entry[0])} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n' for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))`